# Looping over columns and use each column as response variable in regression modelling

Tags: r, loops

I have a big dataframe `"Data_spec"` consists of plot names in the first column, 40 columns explanatory variables and 100 columns response variables. I would like to create a glmer model through looping each response variable columns. Here is the sample data as an example.

[image]

Following code for one column, but how can I loop over each column starting from `col1_exp` to `col5_resp` and create a model for each of them? Any help much appreciated.

```
   model1<- glmer(col1_resp~col1_exp+col2_exp+col3_exp+col4_exp+col5_exp+
                               (1|PlotName),data = Data_spec, family="poisson")
```

Comment: Do you want to create multiple models with different response variables like `glmer(col1_resp~col1_exp+....` and `glmer(col2_resp~col1_exp+` but programmatically?

Comment: @RonakShah, yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :

```
cols <- names(Data_spec)[7:11]

model_list <- lapply(cols, function(x) tryCatch(lme4::glmer(
       paste0(x, "~col1_exp+col2_exp+col3_exp+col4_exp+col5_exp+(1|PlotName)"), 
       data = Data_spec, family="poisson"), error = function(e){}))
```

Comment: @Sher So instead of `cols <- grep('resp', names(Data_spec), value = TRUE)` use `cols <- names(Data_spec)[7:11]`

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, but getting error `boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
  Downdated VtV is not positive definite `

Comment: @Sher I guess this is more because of the data that you have because when I run the same code it works fine on `mtcars` dataset.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ronak, I had dash (-) symbol in the column names which was making this error. However, now I have another error ` Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
  pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations`. I think this error coming from the response variables. I have count data, which means many plots may have 0 values for some species, this may be causing this error. My question is can we add if else statement that, if model doesn't converge for some variables it should continue rather than stopping and throwing an error.

Comment: @Sher you can wrap it in in `tryCatch`, Try `lapply(cols, function(x) tryCatch(lme4::glmer(paste0(x, 
                                            "~col1_exp+col2_exp+col3_exp+col4_exp+col5_exp+(1|PlotName)"),
                                     data = Data_spec, family="poisson"), error = function(e){}))`

Comment: Great @Ronak, is you change `cols <- grep('resp', names(Data_spec), value = TRUE)` to `cols <- names(Data_spec)[7:11]` in Answer I would accept. Big thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sher Great, Updated the answer.